# How is STUN able to bypass a proxy?

Tags: proxy, webrtc, stun

I have written a basic proxy server that swaps the header on incoming and outgoing traffic so that the proxy client requests appear as though originating from the public IP of the server. At least this is the case when going to a site such as [whatismyip.com](https://whatismyip.com). However when I go to a [webRTC leak tests](https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test) the real IP of the client machine is revealed.

I know the STUN protocol, which is being used by WebRTC, is meant to be able to traverse firewalls, NATs, and indeed proxies; but for all the explanations and documentations I have read on the topic I cannot seem to find what is it about the protocol that allows it to bypass a proxy that I know is not revealing the original header information.

So *how* is STUN able to get the information it gets? The best guess I have heard is that it is communicating with the browser to return the next closest hop. But it is still just a guess; can someone explain specifically what is really happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

STUN is running via UDP and not HTTP and if you are using a naive "proxy/vpn" that fails to block this usage it will leak the IP.

Chrome has APIs for extensions to prevent this but it showed most of them do not. See
https://webrtchacks.com/so-your-vpn-is-leaking-because-of-webrtc/ or https://voidsec.com/vpn-leak/ for background information.

Comment: Why does running via UDP and not HTTP matter?

Comment: Chrome will not (by default) attempt to pass UDP traffic over a tcp proxy.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "naive" proxy. I wrote the proxy in Java using ServerSocket to listen for SOCKS5 messages from the client. It then creates a completely new Socket connection to the server, copying the body of the SOCKS5 message across the two separate connections. It does not forward the TCP/IP or UDP/IP headers. From the server's POV, it is only seeing a connection from the proxy where the IP header's sender address is the proxy. 

How is STUN:
1. able bypass the proxy's sender address?
- and -
2. not bypass the address of the router?

Comment: @fernfern - STUN is able to bypass the proxy address simply by ignoring the browser setting. The Stun client code literally just creates a socket and sends as it would if there were no proxy settings.  If the network and firewall environment limits traffic to go explicitly through a proxy, the STUN call will fail.

Comment: @selbie - Thanks, this is the answer I needed. If you want to put it as an actual answer rather than comment then I will mark it as the accepted answer to the question

Comment: @PhilippHancke is there any configuration on chrome we make it traffic goes over TCP proxy?